# Add div classes in XSLT 1.0 with conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css, xslt, xslt-1.0

With my database software, I am able to export my albums collection in HTML with XSL template.
I manage to modify XSL template to support Bootstrap 4.
Now, I'm trying to add an alphabetical filter. I tinkered a javascript and it works but without animation when I apply filter.

So, to add animations (fade in, fade out), like this example here https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/portfolio-gallery-with-filtering-category, I need to add proper classes in a div with XSL in each album according to the first letter of an artist of the album.
**Remark:** my current javascript is temporary, with the right classes in albums, it will be simplified as in the bootsnip.

Because I use a database software to export in HTML, I'm not really able to provide a XML input. But if I export my database in XML, here is a short sample of the result:

```xml
    <musiclist>
<music>
  <id>8881</id>
  <index>237</index>
  <title>A Journey To Rotterdam</title>
  <titlesort>Journey To Rotterdam</titlesort>
  <releasedate>
    <year>
      <displayname>2013</displayname>
    </year>
    <month>5</month>
    <day>18</day>
    <date>18/05/2013</date>
  </releasedate>
  <recordingdate/>
  <artists>
    <artist>
      <displayname>Jepht&#233; Guillaume</displayname>
      <templateimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\JephtGuillaume8878_t.jpg</templateimage>
      <scaledimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\JephtGuillaume8878_i.jpg</scaledimage>
      <sortname>Guillaume, Jepht&#233;</sortname>
      <lastname>Guillaume</lastname>
      <url>https://www.facebook.com/jephte.t.guillaume</url>
      <firstname>Jepht&#233;</firstname>
    </artist>
    <artist>
      <displayname>Diephuis</displayname>
      <templateimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\Diephuis8917_t.jpg</templateimage>
      <scaledimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\Diephuis8917_i.jpg</scaledimage>
      <sortname>Beljaars, Barend-Jan</sortname>
      <lastname>Beljaars</lastname>
      <url>https://www.discogs.com/fr/artist/2569040-Diephuis</url>
      <firstname>Barend-Jan</firstname>
    </artist>
  </artists>
  <artistfirstletter>
    <displayname>G</displayname>
    <sortname>G</sortname>
  </artistfirstletter>
  <composers/>
  <genres>
    <genre>
      <displayname>Deep House</displayname>
    </genre>
    <genre>
      <displayname>Electronic</displayname>
    </genre>
  </genres>
  <notes>100 exemplaires</notes>
  <label>
    <displayname>Sacred Rhythm Music</displayname>
    <templateimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\SacredRhythmMusic818_t.jpg</templateimage>
    <scaledimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\SacredRhythmMusic818_i.jpg</scaledimage>
    <sortname>Sacred Rhythm Music (Joe Claussell)</sortname>
    <lastname>Sacred Rhythm Music (Joe Claussell)</lastname>
    <url>http://www.sacredrhythmmusic.net/news.html</url>
  </label>
  <labelnumber>SRM 266</labelnumber>
  <length>26:31</length>
  <lengthsecs>1591</lengthsecs>
  <nrtracks>3</nrtracks>
  <cddbgenreid1>0</cddbgenreid1>
  <compositions/>
  <submissiondate/>
  <format>
    <displayname>12 inch Vinyl</displayname>
    <templateimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\12inchVinyl168_t.png</templateimage>
    <scaledimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\Vinyl12inchAlbum16.jpg</scaledimage>
  </format>
  <cddbgenreid2>0</cddbgenreid2>
  <rating>0</rating>
  <rating>
    <displayname>0</displayname>
    <sortname>0</sortname>
  </rating>
  <studios/>
  <conductors/>
  <orchestras/>
  <choruses/>
  <musicians/>
  <credits/>
  <hash>{CD9CBF02-6850-484C-913F-C63324D6DF15}</hash>
  <purchasedate>
    <year>
      <displayname>2016</displayname>
    </year>
    <month>1</month>
    <day>13</day>
    <date>13/01/2016</date>
  </purchasedate>
  <purchaseprice>7,55 &#8364;</purchaseprice>
  <origreleasedate/>
  <store>
    <displayname>Bandcamp</displayname>
    <templateimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\Bandcamp8680_t.png</templateimage>
    <scaledimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\Bandcamp8680_i.jpg</scaledimage>
    <sortname>Bandcamp</sortname>
    <lastname>Bandcamp</lastname>
    <url>https://bandcamp.com/</url>
  </store>
  <spars>
    <displayname>DDD</displayname>
  </spars>
  <country>
    <displayname>Etats-Unis</displayname>
    <templateimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\EtatsUnis1000_t.gif</templateimage>
    <scaledimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\EtatsUnis1000_i.jpg</scaledimage>
  </country>
  <sounds>
    <sound>
      <displayname>Stereo</displayname>
    </sound>
  </sounds>
  <extras/>
  <packaging>
    <displayname>Sleeve</displayname>
  </packaging>
  <rare boolvalue="1">Yes</rare>
  <collectionstatus listid="3">In Collection</collectionstatus>
  <nrdiscs>1</nrdiscs>
  <coverfront>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\SRM 266 front.jpg</coverfront>
  <coverback>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\SRM 266 rear.jpg</coverback>
  <backgroundbackdrop>CLZBACKDROP</backgroundbackdrop>
  <bpalbumid>104663034</bpalbumid>
  <links>
    <link>
      <description>6a A Journey To Rotterdam</description>
      <url>https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=720079312</url>
      <urltype>URL</urltype>
    </link>
  </links>
  <condition/>
  <mediacondition/>
  <quantity>1</quantity>
  <lastmodified>
    <date>06/01/2017 16:51:15</date>
  </lastmodified>
  <dateadded>
    <date>19/11/2016 13:30:09</date>
  </dateadded>
  <thumbfilepath>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Thumbnails\6A093329A852EA2DF10C63CADC9F0040.jpg</thumbfilepath>
  <details>
    <detail type="disc">
      <id>8882</id>
      <index>1</index>
      <title>A Journey To Rotterdam</title>
      <titlesort>Journey To Rotterdam</titlesort>
      <releasedate>
        <year>
          <displayname>2013</displayname>
        </year>
        <month>5</month>
        <day>18</day>
        <date>18/05/2013</date>
      </releasedate>
      <recordingdate/>
      <artists>
        <artist>
          <displayname>Jepht&#233; Guillaume</displayname>
          <templateimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\JephtGuillaume8878_t.jpg</templateimage>
          <scaledimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\JephtGuillaume8878_i.jpg</scaledimage>
          <sortname>Guillaume, Jepht&#233;</sortname>
          <lastname>Guillaume</lastname>
          <url>https://www.facebook.com/jephte.t.guillaume</url>
          <firstname>Jepht&#233;</firstname>
        </artist>
        <artist>
          <displayname>Diephuis</displayname>
          <templateimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\Diephuis8917_t.jpg</templateimage>
          <scaledimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\Diephuis8917_i.jpg</scaledimage>
          <sortname>Beljaars, Barend-Jan</sortname>
          <lastname>Beljaars</lastname>
          <url>https://www.discogs.com/fr/artist/2569040-Diephuis</url>
          <firstname>Barend-Jan</firstname>
        </artist>
      </artists>
      <artistfirstletter>
        <displayname>G</displayname>
        <sortname>G</sortname>
      </artistfirstletter>
      <composers/>
      <genres>
        <genre>
          <displayname>Deep House</displayname>
        </genre>
        <genre>
          <displayname>Electronic</displayname>
        </genre>
      </genres>
      <label>
        <displayname>Sacred Rhythm Music</displayname>
        <templateimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\SacredRhythmMusic818_t.jpg</templateimage>
        <scaledimage>C:\Users\Gros_\Documents\Music Collector\Images\Listitemimages\SacredRhythmMusic818_i.jpg</scaledimage>
        <sortname>Sacred Rhythm Music (Joe Claussell)</sortname>
        <lastname>Sacred Rhythm Music (Joe Claussell)</lastname>
        <url>http://www.sacredrhythmmusic.net/news.html</url>
      </label>
      <labelnumber>SRM 266</labelnumber>
      <length>26:31</length>
      <lengthsecs>1591</lengthsecs>
      <nrtracks>3</nrtracks>
      <cddbgenreid1>0</cddbgenreid1>
      <compositions/>
      <submissiondate/>
      <cddbgenreid2>0</cddbgenreid2>
      <rating>0</rating>
      <rating>
        <displayname>0</displayname>
        <sortname>0</sortname>
      </rating>
      <studios/>
      <conductors/>
      <orchestras/>
      <choruses/>
      <musicians/>
      <credits/>
      <bitrate>0</bitrate>
      <filesize>0</filesize>
</music>
</musiclist>
</musicinfo>
```

Here is the XSL part of code I've modified: for each album, I want to retrieve each artist of the album and apply the correct class in album's div according to the first letter of this artist. I handle maximum 5 artists in each album. letter's classes are concatenate with layout Bootstrap classes.

```xsl
<xsl:template match="musiclist">
    <xsl:for-each select="music">
        <div align="center">
            <xsl:for-each select="artists/artist/displayname">
                <xsl:variable name="count"select="position()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="ArtistName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(artists/artist/displayname, 1, 1)"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="first-letter{$count}">
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'A')"> letterA </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'B')"> letterB </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'C')"> letterC </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'D')"> letterD </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'E')"> letterE </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'F')"> letterF </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'G')"> letterG </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'H')"> letterH </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'I')"> letterI </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'J')"> letterJ </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'K')"> letterK </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'L')"> letterL </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'M')"> letterM </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'N')"> letterN </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'O')"> letterO </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'P')"> letterP </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'Q')"> letterQ </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'R')"> letterR </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'S')"> letterS </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'T')"> letterT </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'U')"> letterU </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'V')"> letterV </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'W')"> letterW </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'X')"> letterX </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'Y')"> letterY </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ArtistName= 'Z')"> letterZ </xsl:if>
                </xsl:variable>

            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter ', $first-letter1, $first-letter2, $first-letter3, $first-letter4, $first-letter5 )"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="music">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$details = 'true'">
            <xsl:variable name="the_href">details/<xsl:value-of select="id"/>.html</xsl:variable>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$absolutelinks = 'true'">
                    <xsl:if test="coverfront!=''">
                        <xsl:variable name="the_href">file:///<xsl:value-of select="coverfront"/></xsl:variable>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="coverfront!=''">
                        <xsl:variable name="the_href">images/<xsl:value-of select="id"/>f.jpg</xsl:variable>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>            
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>            
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="thumbfilepath!=''">
            <xsl:variable name="the_img_src">images/<xsl:value-of select="id"/>t.jpg</xsl:variable>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="the_img_src">images/mainitem.jpg</xsl:variable>
        </xsl:otherwise>            
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:variable name="the_caption"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:variable>
    <a href="{$the_href}" title="{$the_caption}" ><img src="{$the_img_src}" class="img-fluid rounded"/></a>
    <xsl:if test="$thumbshowcaption = 'true'">
        <xsl:if test="artists!=''">
            <div class="artist">
                <xsl:for-each select="artists/artist/displayname">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
        <div class="album"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></div>
        <br/>
    </xsl:if>  
</xsl:template>
```

Here you can see the result in HTML for an album:

```html
<div class="row equal" id="album-table">
    <div align="center" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter ">
        <a href="details/8660.html" title="Afrikan Basement - Unreleased Extended Versions - Disc 1">
            <img src="images/8660t.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded"/>
        </a>
        <div class="artist">Bolla</div>
        <div class="album">Afrikan Basement - Unreleased Extended Versions - Disc 1</div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter ">
        <a href="details/8881.html" title="A Journey To Rotterdam">
            <img src="images/8881t.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded"/>
        </a>
        <div class="artist">Jepht&#233; Guillaume | Diephuis</div>
        <div class="album">A Journey To Rotterdam</div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter ">
        <a href="details/376.html" title="La Home Box - Disc 3">
            <img src="images/376t.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded"/>
        </a>
        <div class="artist">Laurent Garnier | Traumer | Bambounou</div>
        <div class="album">La Home Box - Disc 3</div>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

But if my code was correct, the result should look like this:

```html
<div class="row equal" id="album-table">
    <div align="center" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter letterB ">
        <a href="details/8660.html" title="Afrikan Basement - Unreleased Extended Versions - Disc 1">
            <img src="images/8660t.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded"/>
        </a>
        <div class="artist">Bolla</div>
        <div class="album">Afrikan Basement - Unreleased Extended Versions - Disc 1</div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter letterJ letterD ">
        <a href="details/8881.html" title="A Journey To Rotterdam">
            <img src="images/8881t.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded"/>
        </a>
        <div class="artist">Jepht&#233; Guillaume | Diephuis</div>
        <div class="album">A Journey To Rotterdam</div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter letterL letterT letterB ">
        <a href="details/376.html" title="La Home Box - Disc 3">
            <img src="images/376t.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded"/>
        </a>
        <div class="artist">Laurent Garnier | Traumer | Bambounou</div>
        <div class="album">La Home Box - Disc 3</div>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out why XSL does not add the correct class to div whereas the concatenate works.

Have you any hint?

If I am able to add proper classes into div, I will be able to apply a new responsive and animated layout in html, just like [this example here](https://vicstudio.de/StackOverflow/Solutions/1/fadenotworking.html)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your input XML please? Also, are you sure you are getting any output produced? `<xsl:variable name="first-letter{$count}">` is not valid syntax in XSLT (and even if it was, variables are local in scope to the block in which they are defined, and you are trying to reference the variable in a different scope). Thanks.

Comment: hi and thanks for answering. As I said, I use a database software which is able to export in HTML. So I do not really have an xml input. But, I can add an XML export instead of HTML but I don't know if it's relevant.
I'm a noob in coding, I don't know how to be sure if an output is really produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have an XML input somewhere, as XSLT takes an XML document as input to transform, so I am guessing your "database software" is returning the data in XML format for the XSLT to transform.

If are having trouble seeing the XML input, one way to find it is to use the [XSLT identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which will produce an output that is the same as the input.

Anyway, for the purposes of answering your question, I am assuming your XML looks like this...

```
<musiclist>
    <music>
        <id>8660</id>
        <title>Afrikan Basement - Unreleased Extended Versions - Disc 1</title>
        <thumbfilepath>?</thumbfilepath>
        <coverfront>?</coverfront>
        <artists>
            <artist><displayname>Bolla</displayname></artist>
        </artists>
    </music>
    <music>
        <id>8881</id>
        <title>A Journey To Rotterdam</title>
        <thumbfilepath>?</thumbfilepath>
        <coverfront>?</coverfront>
        <artists>
            <artist><displayname>Jepht&#233; Guillaume</displayname></artist>
            <artist><displayname>Diephuis</displayname></artist>
        </artists>
    </music>
    <music>
        <id>376</id>
        <title>La Home Box - Disc 3</title>
        <thumbfilepath>?</thumbfilepath>
        <coverfront>?</coverfront>
        <artists>
            <artist><displayname>Laurent Garnier</displayname></artist>
            <artist><displayname>Traumer</displayname></artist>
            <artist><displayname>Bamboun</displayname></artist>
        </artists>
    </music>
</musiclist>
```

The first problem in your XSLT is how you define the variable

```
<xsl:variable name="ArtistName">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(artists/artist/displayname, 1, 1)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Your are already positioned on a `displayname` element at this point, so the xpath `artists/artist/displayname` is going to look for a child element of `displayname` called `artists`, which does not exist. The whole statement can be simplified to this...

```
<xsl:variable name="ArtistName" select="substring(., 1, 1)"/>
```

(In fact, you don't really need to use a variable here, as will be seen shortly)

The second issue is that this is not valid syntax. You cannot have dynamic variable names.

```
<xsl:variable name="first-letter{$count}">
```

Even if this was valid, the variable is being defined in an `xsl:for-each` block, so it would be restricted to this scope, but you are trying to use it after the `xsl:for-each` where it is out of scope.

Your list of `xsl:if` is also a bit repetitive, and also won't output anything anyway because you are checking for `ArtistName`, which looks for an element named `ArtistName`. You should have been using `$ArtistName`, to check the variable.

Anyway, to cut a long story short, you can simplify the whole template to this. So rather than using variables, you dynamically build the class string within the `xsl:attribute` block

```
<xsl:template match="musiclist">
    <xsl:for-each select="music">
        <div align="center">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:text>col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter</xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="artists/artist/displayname">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' letter', substring(., 1, 1))" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the template matching music also suffers from the issue with variable scope. Where variables may be useful, you just need to put the `xsl:choose` statement within the `xsl:variable` block, rather than the other way around.

Try this XSLT for starters....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="details" select="'true'" />
    <xsl:param name="absolutelinks" select="'true'" />
    <xsl:param name="thumbshowcaption" select="'true'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div class="row equal" id="album-table">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="musiclist">
        <xsl:for-each select="music">
            <div align="center">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:text>col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="artists/artist/displayname">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' letter', substring(., 1, 1))" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="music">
        <xsl:variable name="the_href">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$details = 'true'">
                    <xsl:text>details/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="id"/><xsl:text>.html</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$absolutelinks = 'true'">
                    <xsl:if test="coverfront!=''">
                        <xsl:text>file:///</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="coverfront"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="coverfront!=''">
                        <xsl:text>images/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="id"/><xsl:text>f.jpg</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>            
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="the_img_src">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="thumbfilepath != ''">
                    <xsl:text>images/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="id"/><xsl:text>t.jpg</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>images/mainitem.jpg</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>            
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <a href="{$the_href}" title="{title}" >
            <img src="{$the_img_src}" class="img-fluid rounded"/>
        </a>

        <xsl:if test="$thumbshowcaption = 'true'">
            <xsl:if test="artists!=''">
                <div class="artist">
                    <xsl:for-each select="artists/artist/displayname">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                            <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
            <div class="album"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></div>
            <br/>
        </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see it in action at http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy1N

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I need, it works fine. Huge thank. I was so far away from the correct answer...